# opencv undistort() doesn't work in vs2010 while works in Qtcreator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, qt-creator, camera-calibration

I found a problem in opencv2.4.8 undistort() in vs2010. It just show me one color image in "undist" window, while the same codes work fine in Qtcreator.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;


int main()
{

         VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
         if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
         return -1;

       while(1)
       {
         Mat frame;
         cap >> frame; 
         imshow("video",frame);

         double cM[3][3] = {{610.12376,0,319.5}, {0,610.12376,239.5}, {0, 0, 1}};
         Mat cameraMatrix = Mat(3, 3,CV_64F,cM);
         double dM[5]={0.0681495,-0.128756,0,0,0.5857514};
         Mat distCoeffs = Mat(8, 1, CV_64F,dM);
         Mat undi=frame.clone();
         undistort(frame,undi, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs);
         imshow("undist",undi);

         if ( (cvWaitKey(30) & 255) == 's' )
         {
             imwrite("test.jpg",undi);
         }
         else if ( (cvWaitKey(30) & 255) == 27 ) break;
     }


    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you link to the same opencv libs? Not mixed debug and release libs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes,same libs, I just use debug libs.. So confused..